# How do I loop through categorised blocks of rows with an empty row seperating?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a table similar to the following

| Sku Name | Category | Items Sold | Weekly Average | In Stock | Supply Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue T-Shirt | Shirts | 32 | 16 | 3 | 6.23 |
| Black T-Shirt | Shirts | 40 | 20 | 5 | 6.23 |
| ~~~~~~~~ |  |  |  |  |  |
| Blue Denim | Shorts | 18 | 9 | 4 | 11.32 |
| Black Denim | Shorts | 6 | 3 | 6 | 11.32 |
| ~~~~~~~~ |  |  |  |  |  |
| Black Hightop | Shoes | 3 | 1.5 | 2 | 21.45 |
| White Hightop | Shoes | 6 | 3 | 5 | 21.45 |

I'm trying to run a loop through each of these blocks by category where it will calculate what % each item makes up of the total sales across that category, for example, what percentage does Black Hightop make up of total shoe sales. It will then put each percentage in column "Z" for future processing.

I can't work out how to nest the loops through so it knows when there are no more categories.

I previously had it working where it wasn't broken down into each category, however, wasn't accurate as it compared sales against the whole catalog, the code I had that worked was

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
orderSold = Application.Sum(Range("D:D"))
orderStock = Application.Sum(Range("E:E"))
Order = orderSold - orderStock
totalSales = Application.Sum(Range("C:C"))

For i = Last To 1 Step -1
Cells(i, "Z").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-23]/ " & totalSales
Next
```

Any help to modify this so it works across each category would be greatly appreciated!

I tried the following and I can see why the program crashed but don't understand where to go from here

```
'Each Category
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Do Until Cells(i + 1).Value = "" & Cells(i + 2).Value = ""
totalSales = Cells(i).End(xlUp).Value
Cells(i, "Z").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-23]/" & totalSales
Loop
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a Pivot table? Looping over the data is dangerous because you need to assure that noone destroys the order of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Dictionary` object to sum up total sales of category

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, arrRes
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data into an array
    Set rngData = Range("A2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 0)
    ' Loop through data to calculate total sales of category
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 2)
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) + arrData(i, 3)
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Populate percent
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 2)
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then _
        arrRes(i, 0) = arrData(i, 3) / objDic(sKey)
    Next i
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("Z2").Resize(UBound(arrData), 1) = arrRes
    Columns("Z").Style = "Percent"
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Style object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.style?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm176072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider adjusting your approach as Excel has evolved to the point where VBA is hardly needed to accomplish what you want. Put this formula in cell `z2` and you'll have the dynamic result you need.

```
=LET(cData,DROP(FILTER($A:$C,$A:$A<>""),1),
 catCol,INDEX(cData,,2),vCol,INDEX(cData,,3),
catSum,BYROW(catCol,LAMBDA(iRow,
SUM(FILTER(vCol,iRow=catCol)))),IFERROR(vCol/catSum,""))
```

Advantages include:

- Does not require VBA

  - Reduced security risks
  - Easier for others to use
  - Less code (though it is a long formula)
  - Does not require execution/event to be fired
- Can be run on Excel for web
- Easier to debug/troubleshoot on single screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this formula in the cells of Column Z. Place in Z2 and drag down (copy/paste). You can set them from VBA with the cells `Formula` property also.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",C2/SUMIF(B$2:B$9,B2,C$2:C$9))
```

Result:

[image]